# triggered email functionality

Tags: marketing-cloud, trigggers

Every ESP I've ever worked with that had trigger/autoresponder functionality requires to simply attach content to the list for triggered emails to fire.

With SFMC, it seems impossible to simply match `DataExtension` with trigger email content for the triggers to go out.  It requires API call for each email - am I correct?

Answer (score 1):

No, that's not correct.

You can trigger an SFMC email to multiple recipients two ways:

1. Firing a [Triggered Send Definition](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/triggered_emails/) with multiple subscribers in the form of a API payload
2. Sending a [User-Initiated Send](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/email_messages/) with a predetermined data source

Both can be created and initiated with the SFMC web services.

Comment: Thanks Adam.  1) involves API and are you sure about 2) send options for user-initiated include only these (both are not triggered sends) : 
Start immediately, run once
Start on the following date and time, run once

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. Triggered Send is queued to send immediately (with the recipients included in the call).  For the UI Send you tell it to send now or in the future.  The UI Send Definition dictates the audience.

Comment: But you can only launch User Initiated Email Once.  In other words, it will not go out by itself each time a new record is added to the dataextension.

Comment: There are List based welcome emails and Journey Builder options to do the "by itself" part.    If it's all API you can make the calls externally.

Comment: Yes, I think by List based welcome emails you're referring to Simple Automates Emails, but unfortunately those only work on lists not dataextensions.

So it looks like the only way to fire a trigger to new records being added to dataextensions is via API call then.

Comment: Or via Journey Builder activity.